# How to use Vue component when I do not use npm/yarn?

Tags: vue.js

How to use Vue component from npmjs.com when I do not use npm/yarn?
Here is an example component I want to use:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-autocomplete

```
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

Comment: Why would you not use npm or yarn for this?

Comment: git clone? https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-google-autocomplete

Comment: Because my code is just a simple Vue.js script on one subpage.

Comment: Just download the .vue file from [here](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/vue-google-autocomplete) and add it to your project and import as normal

Comment: See if it has a CDN.

Comment: You can't because this package doesn't provide prebuilt js file. Consider using modern tools (NPM, Vue CLI) even for simple projects because otherwise you limit yourself to third-party libs that can work with vanilla JS out of the box.